# Mui - remix with typescript - Set primary color in theme via .env

Tags: material-ui, remix.run

Since remix.run renders serverside, I expect it would be possible to set colors via .env file. But in the [entry.client.tsx](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/examples/remix-with-typescript/app/entry.client.tsx) the theme is imported and set in the ThemeProvider. When the color palette uses .env variables it breaks in the browser, because process is not defined.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'light',
    primary: {
      main: process.env.PRIMARY_COLOR,
    },
  }
});
```

Any ideas how to use .env to create a theme?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to import the theme on the `root.tsx` and fetching the environment data from the loader.

1. Created a `.env` and setted the primary color:

`PRIMARY_COLOR="#FF0000"` with `""`

2. On `root.tsx`, created a loader function:

```
export async function loader() {  
  return json({
    ENV: {
      PRIMARY_COLOR: process.env.PRIMARY_COLOR,
    },
  });
}
```

3. At the App function fetched the env variable and created the theme:

```
export default function App() {
  const data = useLoaderData();  

  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: data.ENV.PRIMARY_COLOR,
      },
    },
  });

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>        
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Outlet />
        </ThemeProvider>
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```